# HTTP client metrics issue for Pooled ConnectionProvider - Unable to start reactive web server

Tags: httpclient, netty, project-reactor, metrics, reactor-netty

Wanted to use additional HTTP client metrics for Pooled ConnectionProvider metrics:

```
reactor.netty.connection.provider.total.connections  
reactor.netty.connection.provider.active.connections  
reactor.netty.connection.provider.idle.connections  
reactor.netty.connection.provider.pending.connections
```

When try to run below sample, it works and shows some active connections etc in console

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Metrics.globalRegistry 
           .config()
           .meterFilter(MeterFilter.maximumAllowableTags("reactor.netty.http.client", "URI", 100, MeterFilter.deny()));

    HttpClient client =
            HttpClient.create()
                      .metrics(true, s -> {
                          if (s.startsWith("/stream/")) { 
                              return "/stream/{n}";
                          }
                          else if (s.startsWith("/bytes/")) {
                              return "/bytes/{n}";
                          }
                          return s;
                      }); 

    client.get()
          .uri("https://httpbin.org/stream/2")
          .responseContent()
          .blockLast();

    client.get()
          .uri("https://httpbin.org/bytes/1024")
          .responseContent()
          .blockLast();
}
```

But when I try to integrate this same in my project, then it results in error. Even I tried with basis HttpClient metrics sample by integrating in my project,

@Component
public class HttpClientConfig implements BeanPostProcessor {

```
@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitializationA(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {

    HttpClient client =
            HttpClient.create()
                    .host("example.com")
                    .port(80);

    client.get()
            .uri("/")
            .response()
            .block();
    return client;
}
```

}

It shows below errors:--

***org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedNetty': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.brave.BraveBridgeConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is*** org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'braveTracer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:81)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:63)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
at com.companyA.ha.http_gateway.HttpGatewayApplication.main(HttpGatewayApplication.java:29)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.ReactiveWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedNetty': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.brave.BraveBridgeConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'braveTracer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:90)
at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:78)
... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.brave.BraveBridgeConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'braveTracer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:610)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.internal.LazyBean.getOrError(LazyBean.java:79)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.contextWithBeans(ReactorSleuth.java:185)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$springContextSpanOperator$3(ReactorSleuth.java:215)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoLift.subscribeOrReturn(MonoLift.java:41)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4384)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1705)
at com.companyA.ha.http_gateway.util.HttpClientConfig.postProcessAfterInitialization(HttpClientConfig.java:27)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
... 24 common frames omitted
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1706)
... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'braveTracer': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.beforeSingletonCreation(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:355)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:227)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:233)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1273)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:494)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:349)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.internal.LazyBean.getOrError(LazyBean.java:79)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.contextWithBeans(ReactorSleuth.java:185)
at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ReactorSleuth.lambda$springContextSpanOperator$3(ReactorSleuth.java:215)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoLift.subscribeOrReturn(MonoLift.java:41)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4384)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1705)
at com.companyA.ha.http_gateway.util.HttpClientConfig.postProcessAfterInitialization(HttpClientConfig.java:27)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:437)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
... 54 common frames omitted
**Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error**

**I have using below dependencies in my pom.xml files**

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
        <boot.version>2.4.5</boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2020.0.12</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyA.ha</groupId>
            <artifactId>hgwcommon-lib</artifactId>
            <!-- TODO: Change it to released version -->
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Metrics related dependencies -->
        <!-- Thanos dependency (do not include other ngp related metrics dependencies) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.companyA.ngp.ar.starters</groupId>
            <artifactId>ngp-spring-boot-starter-metrics-thanos-registryA</artifactId>
            <version>2021.06.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepositoryA.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
                <artifactId>reactor-netty-core</artifactId>

            </dependency>
        

<dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty-http</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**I have tried everything found while searching for it (Although very limited found). Nothing worked for me. Stucked in it from few days.
Please guide, how to use the above Pooled ConnectionProvider metrics. and why these errors are coming...**